# linking an output from on entity to the input of another entity

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to connect the output of an entity to the input of another entity.
Eventually connect a third entity will be connected,but i want to understand the process of connecting two entity's together.

Do I use a port map? If I do, are they added to both architectures of the different entity's to link them?

I know it wont be as simple as below:

```
link: transmitter port map (output_e1=>input_e2);
```

I have tried this but an error returns using ModelSim pointing at components declarations!

### update:

```
ENTITY transmitter is   
    port(  
        transmission : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0)
    );  
end transmitter;        

architecture Behavioral of transmitter  is  
end Behavioral;  

Entity receiver is   
    PORT(  
        rxi:in signed (7 downto 0)
end receiver;  

architecture Behavioral of receiver is 
end Behavioral;
```

The above code does not include all the instructions and commands. My program works, but i have two entity and wish to link them as they would be in a communications system.

Comment: Please include a minimal code example that shows your problem. A single line of code in isolation is not sufficient.

Comment: VHDL is a _hardware_ description language. How would you connect the output of one piece of hardware (ie one entity) to the input of another? You'd use a piece of metal (a wire, a PCB track etc). The construct in VHDL that presents such pieces of metal is a _signal_.  You need enough signals  and you need to connect the outputs of your first entity to those signals (using a port map) and to the inputs of the next (also using a port map).

Comment: Provide a block diagram showing the connections.

Answer (score 1):

See the following example, a full adder circuit done using two half adders. You can see how the first half adder output is connected as the input of 2nd half adder.

```
    --top module(full adder) entity declaration
entity fulladder is
    port (a : in std_logic;
            b : in std_logic;
           cin : in std_logic;
           sum : out std_logic;
           carry : out std_logic
         );
end fulladder;
--top module architecture declaration.
architecture behavior of fulladder is
--sub-module(half adder) is declared as a component before the keyword "begin".
   component halfadder
    port(
         a : in std_logic;
         b : in std_logic;
         sum : out std_logic;
         carry : out std_logic
        );
    end component;
--All the signals are declared here,which are not a part of the top module.
--These are temporary signals like 'wire' in Verilog.
signal s1,c1,c2 : std_logic:='0';

begin
--instantiate and do port map for the first half adder.
  HA1 : halfadder port map (
          a => a,
          b => b,
          sum => s1,
          carry => c1
        );
--instantiate and do port map for the second half adder.
 HA2 : halfadder port map (
          a => s1,
          b => cin,
         sum => sum,
         carry => c2
        );
carry <= c1 or c2;  --final carry calculation

end;
```

See this [link](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.in/2010/03/usage-of-components-and-port-mapping.html) for explanation.

Comment: this only has one entity,i have updated my original question.